# How to put javascript variables from a form into a config file

Tags: javascript, json, calendar, config

I have a form (in Caspio Bridge) that the user fills out to create an event in a calendar. I'm using an 'Add to Calendar' module from an outside source (https://github.com/jekuer/add-to-calendar-button) to create a file for downloading to various calendars (google, ical, etc.).

In the Caspio form `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/add-to-calendar-button@1.8/assets/css/atcb.min.css">` and `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/add-to-calendar-button@1.8" defer></script>` are referenced to pull in the various files needed.

In the Caspio form a button click creates a config file that is used to create the download file and open the download options buttons.

I need to pull variables (event title, description, start date/time, end date/time) from the form, after the user enters data, and use those variables in creating the config file when the user clicks the Submit button. How is this done? Also, I can only alter the code shown here, not the referenced files.

Here are the javascript variables that get the user's input from the form:

```js
var v_name = document.getElementById('InsertRecordTasksTimeline_Title').value;
var v_note = document.getElementById('InsertRecordTasksTimeline_Notes').value;
var v_location = document.getElementsByName('InsertRecordTasksTimeline_Location')[0].value;

 Stamp = new Date(document.getElementById('InsertRecordTasksTimeline_CalDate').value);
 Hours = Stamp.getHours()
 Mins = Stamp.getMinutes();
v_BeginDate=('' + Stamp.getFullYear() +"-"+ (Stamp.getMonth()+1) + "-" + Stamp.getDate() +"T"+  Hours + ":" + Mins);

Stamp2 = new Date(document.getElementById('InsertRecordTasksTimeline_CalEnd').value);
 Hours = Stamp2.getHours()
 Mins = Stamp2.getMinutes();
v_EndDate=('' + Stamp2.getFullYear() +"-"+ (Stamp2.getMonth()+1) + "-" + Stamp2.getDate() +"T"+  Hours + ":" + Mins);
```

And here is the basic button that creates the config file: `<button id="default-button" name="submitevent3">Submit</button>`

Below is the code I have in the Caspio form that creates the config file, opens the download button options, and downloads a calendar file (.ics, etc). Note, for the values in this example there are just placeholders.

I somehow need to get the variables v_name, v_note, v_BeginDate, v_EndDate into the Config file so that name:v_name, description:v_note, startDate:v_BeginDate, endDate:v_EndDate. How would that be done?

```js
 const config = {

    "name": "event title vale",
    "description": "event note value",
    "startDate" : "2022-06-01T10:15",
    "endDate": "2022-06-01T12:30",
    "location":"event location",
    options: ["Google", "Apple","Microsoft365"],
    timeZone: "currentBrowser",
    trigger: "click",
    iCalFileName: "Reminder-Event",
  }
  const button = document.querySelector('#default-button')
  button.addEventListener('click', ()=> atcb_action(config, button)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer if anyone needs it. I have some code run onmouseover of a div with buttons in it. This code gets the variables and puts them in the config file. When one of the buttons is clicked it runs the config and the export options are available.

```js
//*** SAVE Get variables and run EXPORT config**

document.querySelector("#divsave").addEventListener("mouseover", function getexport(){

const v_name = document.getElementById('InsertRecordTasksTimeline_Title').value;
const v_note = document.getElementById('InsertRecordTasksTimeline_Notes').value;
const v_proj = document.getElementsByName('cbParamVirtual11')[0].value;
const v_descrip = "Project: " + v_proj + "<br />" + v_note;

const sday = document.getElementById('cbParamVirtual15').value;
const eday = document.getElementById('cbParamVirtual10').value;

const stime = document.getElementById('timepicker').value;
const etime = document.getElementById('timepicker2').value;

const c_sday = new Date(sday).toLocaleDateString('fr-CA');
const c_eday = new Date(eday).toLocaleDateString('fr-CA');

const config = {

name: v_name,
description: v_descrip,
startDate: c_sday,
endDate: c_eday,
startTime: stime,
endTime: etime,
options: ["Apple",
    "Google",
    "iCal|ics file",
    "Microsoft365",
    "MicrosoftTeams",
    "Outlook.com",],
timeZone: "currentBrowser",
trigger: "click",
iCalFileName: "Reminder-Event",
}

const button = document.querySelector('#default-button')
button.addEventListener('click', ()=> atcb_action(config, button)
)

});
```